# Run metasploit console resource scripts

Tags: penetration-test, metasploit, meterpreter

Hi I want to do this in my lab environment:

When meterpreter shell is gained, automatically I want to execute console commands such as `route add`, `jobs -K` or use some other exploit or auxiliary modules. There is `multicommand` , `multi_console_command`  and other ruby scripts to do that using `AutoRunScript` option in msf handler. Unfortunately all of those scripts only run commands in `meterpreter` session and I want to change this logic. I want to run them in console. Consider this scenario, you want to kill job when session is come and add route then run another auxiliary module.

How to do that?

Comment: In that link, only shown running commands using resource scripts in meterpreter session context. I want to run  commands  in metasploit console context.

Comment: Ask mubix, he probably knows https://twitter.com/mubix

Answer (score 1):

`multi_console_command.rb` (by darkoperator) uses the meterpreter APi `cmd_exec()` to execute a list of commands.

The metasploit API that allows us to use the shell interpreter is: `session.shell_command()`

Option 1:
build your own `multi_console_command.rb` module with `session.shell_command()` API
Option 2: build one **resource file** with those post-exploitation commands

My metasploit API cheat sheet list:
https://github.com/r00t-3xp10it/hacking-material-books/blob/master/metasploit-RC%5BERB%5D/metasploit-API/my-API-Cheat-sheet.md

My metasploit resource files cheat sheet:
https://github.com/r00t-3xp10it/hacking-material-books/blob/master/metasploit-RC%5BERB%5D/metasploit_resource_files.md

Answer (score -1):

When you're in the meterpreter console you need to use the `background` command to return to the msfconsole screen.

```
meterpreter > background
[*] Backgrounding session 2...
msf > route add 10.10.0.0/24 2
[*] Route added
msf > sessions -l

Active sessions
===============

  Id  Name  Type                     Information                 Connection
  --  ----  ----                     -----------                 ----------
  2         meterpreter x86/windows  test\test @ test  192.168.15.58:443 -> 192.168.15.180:49271 (192.168.15.180)

msf > sessions -i 2
[*] Starting interaction with 2...
```

Comment: I think you didn't get the point. I want to automate this process. When meterpreter shell is gained, automatically I want to execute console commands such as route add, jobs -K or use some other exploit or auxiliary modules. There is multicommand,multi_console_command and other ruby scripts to do that using AutoRunScript option in msf handler. Unfortunately all of those scripts only run commands in meterpreter session and I want to change this logic. I want to run them in console. Consider this scenario, you want to kill job when session is come and add route then run another auxiliary module.